# socks5 proxy internet

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer

Can IE 8/9 be configured to use SOCKS5 proxy? I'm trying to make Internet Explorer to work with Socks5 proxy, but seems it's not supporting Socks5 ?

```
r.WriteInteger('ProxyEnable', 1);
r.WriteString('ProxyServer', 'socks=127.0.0.1:1080'); // no support for socks5?
```

My Socks server is Socks5 only (no v4 support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately IE 8 and 9 only allow version 4

Comment: This is really not a Delphi programming question, or a programming question at all.  But because of the bounty, apparently, I can't even vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Us a v4 proxy (Delphi: http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/examplesocks4proxybyaphex )